# How to allow parent id attribute in child strong parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

There is a two models `StudyMaterial` and `Card`.

```
class StudyMaterial < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :study_material
end
```

I set a strong parameter like this.

```
def card_params
  params.require(:card).permit(:front, :back, :tips, :cardtype, :study_material_id)
end
```

I get a log like this when a card is created.

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "card"=>{"front"=>"front", "back"=>"back"}, "commit"=>"Create Card", "study_material_id"=>"1"}
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "cards" ("back", "created_at", "front", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["back", "back"], ["cardtype", ""], ["created_at", Mon, 31 Mar 2014 10:30:59 UTC +00:00], ["front", "front"], ["updated_at", Mon, 31 Mar 2014 10:30:59 UTC +00:00]]
   (2.9ms)  commit transaction
```

It looks like `study_material_id` is not saved to database.
I think this is about strong parameters, how should I write to pass `study_material_id`?

*Edit [Add views and controller]*

This is `views/study_materials/show.html.erb`

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<%= render 'cards/form' %>
```

and `views/cards/_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for([@study_material, @card]) do |f| %>
  <% if @card.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@card.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this card from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @card.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :front %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :front %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :back %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :back %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And `controllers/study_materials_controller.rb`

```
class StudyMaterialsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_study_material, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # ...
  def show
    @card = @study_material.cards.build
  end
  # ...
  private
    def set_study_material
      @study_material = StudyMaterial.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Comment: `study_material_id` outside in form `card` , provide `form.erb.html` or views with form please.

Comment: Do you have `study_material_id` in your `params`?

Comment: @Magnuss look in `log`.

Comment: @Monk_Code I added views and controllers. How can I fix error?

Comment: try reverse `[@study_material, @card]` to `[@card, @study_material]`

Comment: Then I got a error `undefined method `card_study_material_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa364d87c28>:0x007fa36579c768>`. Is there anything that I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `study_material_id` inside your form:

```
<%= form_for([@study_material, @card]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :study_material_id, :value => @study_material.id %>
  ...
```

That way study_material_id should be defined inside `params[:card]` and so passed through to the model.